# Avahi service fails with enable-dbus=no

Tags: printing, dbus, avahi

Xubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
In an attempt to remove "ghost printers" from showing up in print dialogs, I added "enable-dbus=no" to my /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf.

I think it gives the proper behavior I want, but it appears adding enable-dbus=no makes avahi fail on start.

Here's what I see with "sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb"

```
Jul 29 17:08:42 xubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
-- Subject: Unit avahi-daemon.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit avahi-daemon.service has failed.
```

Is enable-dbus=no not a valid option for the config file for avahi?

Comment: Seems that it's not, at least currently: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/1507247